# add parameter with htaccess file

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress installation, and it runs the following .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /TestWordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /TestWordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And I have a page named checkout, so I want the following

Everytime the /checkout/ page is loaded,
add a parameter at the end: /checkout?myparam=1

I've tried the following

```
# add a trailing param to /checkout
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?checkout/$ $1checkout?myparam=1 [R=301,L]
```

also without the R=301, but still does not work.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule just below `RewriteBase /TestWordpress/` line:

```
RewriteRule (^|/)checkout/?$ $0?myparam=1 [QSA,NC,L]
```